# CSS one class to ignore another

Tags: html, css

I have something like this

```
<div class="text-holder">
    <h2>this is text-holder</h2>
    <p>this is text</p>
</div>
<a href="#" class="ignore">
    <div class="text-holder">
        <h2>this is text-holder</h2>
        <p>this is text</p>
    </div>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <div class="text-holder">
        <h2>this is text-holder</h2>
        <p>this is text</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

And CSS that does this

```
.text-holder {
    color: green;
}
a {
    color: red;
    other css
}
.ignore {
    other css
}
```

Is there a way that the link can ignore the css style for the global a style, and just use the ignore? I don't want to use `!important` because there will be other instances of text-holder that will want to use the global a style.

**EDIT**

Thanks for all the replies, but let me be a little more clear so hopefully you understand better. (Not the best at explaining)

The problem is `text-holder` has it's text styling from global `p`, `h2` and etc. Which are above a in the hierarchy of the stylesheet. so `p`, `h2`, `a`, `.ignore`, `.text-holder` etc

`a` has a lot of info on it, `hover`, `visited`, `focus`, `color`, `font-weight` and etc. Now for all the divs I wanted to ignore this info I was looking to see if there was a simpler way of just creating an `ignore` rule, rather than for all the divs I want to ignore it to overwrite them with all the rewritten information.

Comment: CSS only overrides, so you could make your class more specific and override with whatever you wanted (`a.ignore{color: auto;}`) for example.

Comment: u need to use a more specific selector to do this like `a.ignore`

Comment: That still won't work as intended.

Comment: what is the exact behaviour you want to have?

Comment: I've added a little more to the question, hopefully this covers everything (this time)

Comment: Re: your edit: the simplest way to do what you want *is* to add an `.ignore` rule to the divs you want to ignore, and user styles to counteract the styles you have applied globally.

Comment: It's a really interesting point you make @TylerH but wouldn't that not work if I applied it to a header, as well as a paragraph? The only way I'd know to stop the effects would be to set them to inherit, which would ignore the rules set earlier to them wouldn't it?

Comment: @Sjrsmile I'm not sure I understand your scenario. Classes can be applied to any element. What matters is that the `.ignore` class appears *after* the original CSS that styles the elements you want ignored.

Comment: @TylerH Yes but I was thinking more where the class is set in the style sheet, I thought that putting the ignore class after a (which is after p, h2 and all the rest) putting it to :inherit would have ignored the rest of the global styles, but it hasn't! So What you actually recommend has worked. Thank you.

Comment: 1) add a css resetter to your stylesheet 2) if needed you can handle some of your needs with "inherit" value and subsequent rewritten value "!important"

Comment: @MrPk `!important` is an unwieldy hack that should be avoided wherever possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't support "ignoring", but part of its nature (the Cascading part of Cascading Style Sheets) supports "overwriting"; Newer CSS properties will overwrite older CSS properties of the same name, so you just need to give `.ignore` a different `color` value than your previous `a` selector's `color` value.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way that the link can ignore the css style for the global a style, and just use the ignore?

No. If a selector matches then all applicable rules in it will be applied.

`.ignore` is at least as specific as all preceding rules, so you just need to set the properties you want to override to the desired value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, basically what you're trying to do is already how CSS works.

The key to understand is the concept of [specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

- CSS rules applied through the `style=""` attribute have a weight of **1000**.
- Rules applied against an `#id` selector have a weight of **100**.
- Rules applied against a `.class` selector have a weight of **10**.
- And rules applied against an `element` tag name or `:pseudo-selector` get a weight of **1**.

So for example, if you have...

```
a { color: red; }
.ignore { color: black; }
```

The weight of the `red` links is **1**, while the weight of `black` text is **10**, so the black has higher specificity and would win.

The important concept is that `.ignore` doesn't tell it to ignore its old assignment, it is instead a way to *override* the assignment.

*EDIT*

I should also add that cascading rules have no weight, so any definition in a child element will override them.

For example:

```
a { color: red; }
.ignore { color: black; }
div { color: blue; }

<a class="ignore"><div>hello world</div></a>
```

The text will be blue, not black, because the `div` tag has a rule applied to it which overrides the cascading black from the `.ignore` class.

Comment: Thank you for this, really appreciate the extra info, this is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
:not(.ignore) .text-holder {
    color: green;
}
```

Or if you move your ignore class to .text-holder element

```
.text-holder:not(.ignore) {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't quite work for what I wanted, but thanks for your time.